# ES.next decorators that get called either directly or as a factory function

Tags: javascript, decorator, ecmascript-next

I have looking at some example of the the ES.next decorators and noticed that it might be possible to make a decorator that gets applied as a factor function that takes arguments, or directly by omitting the `()` at the end at the same time.

I managed to get either styles to work separately, as a factory function `@decorate(withArgs)`, or directly `@decorate`, but not both!

Here's an example:
https://github.com/jayphelps/core-decorators.js#deprecate-alias-deprecated

```
class foo {

  @deprecate
  foo() {}

  @deprecate("with an optional string")
  bar() {}
}
```

I tried to examine the source code mentioned above, but with my limited experience with decorators, I couldn't figure out how to set up something like that.

---

Here's how I managed to get `@decorate` to work without using any arguments

```
function decorate(target, key, descriptor) {
  // do some stuff and then return the new descriptor
}
```

and here's how I managed to get `@decorate(args)` to work with arguments as a factory function:

```
function decorate(...args) {
  return function(target, key, descriptor) {
    // do some stuff using args and then return the new descriptor
  }
}
```

As you can see, at the point it's either `decorate foo()` or `decorate(args) foo()`, not both.

Comment: Did you write your own implementation of @deprecate (if so, post it)? Or are you having trouble getting their example to work?

Comment: @RobM. I did updated the question to show my implementation, I'm not concerned about the actual implementation of `deprecate`. I'm trying to get a decorator to work with or without `()` at the end.

Comment: Hi, if my answer solves your problem, can you please mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing `@decorator` the browser expects that **the decorator function is called immediately**, where as, when writing `@decorator(args)` it expects that **a factory is called first, which will return a decorator function**.

Here's an example of a decorator i wrote that adds a state property to a class
that is driven by redux

```
export default function state (defaultState) {

    function reducer(state, action) {
        if (!state) {
            state = defaultState;
        }
        ...
    }

    function decorator (target) {...}

    // If 1st argument is a function, it means `@state` was written
    if (typeof defaultState === 'function') {
        let target = defaultState;
        defaultState = {};
        return decorator(target);
    } else {
        return decorator;
    }
}
```

> Do note, that the decorator in the example is a **class decorator**, which
>   has a different signature `(target)` than the **method decorator** you are
>   writing `(target, key, descriptor)`

The decorator can be used with or without a parameter

```
import state from './decorators/redux-state'

@state({
    name: '',
})
class MyClass {
    ...
}

@state
class MyOtherClass {
    constructor(state= {name: ''}) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    ...
}
```

Jay Phelps, is abstracting the logic of figuring out how the decorator was called in a `decorate` utility function, and that makis his code harder to follow.

Hope this helps